# How to make the code more simple with Looping or Array?

Tags: c

i'm trying to learn new algorythm with struct in c, then i try to make some test. But the code is too long and i want to make it more simple.

```
struct employee{
  char ID[6];
  char name[20];
  char address[50];
  long salary;
  long T;
}casher1,casher2;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int ch;
  printf("Choose : ");
  scanf("%d",&ch );
  if (ch == 1) {
    printf("Input Name : " );
    scanf("%s",casher1.name );
    printf("Input ID : " );
    scanf("%s",casher1.ID );
    printf("Input Salary : " );
    scanf("%d",&casher1.salary);
    printf("Input T : " );
    scanf("%d",&casher1.T );
    printf("\n");
    casher1.salary = casher1.salary + casher1.T;

    printf("ID : %s\n",casher1.ID );
    printf("Name : %s\n",casher1.name );
    printf("Salary : %d\n",casher1.salary );
  }
  else if(ch == 2) {
    printf("Input Name : " );
    scanf("%s",casher2.name );
    printf("Input ID : " );
    scanf("%s",casher2.ID );
    printf("Input Salary : " );
    scanf("%d",&casher2.salary);
    printf("Input T : " );
    scanf("%d",&casher2.T );
    printf("\n");
    casher2.salary = casher2.salary + casher2.T;

    printf("ID : %s\n",casher2.ID );
    printf("Name : %s\n",casher2.name );
    printf("Salary : %d\n",casher2.salary );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I'd expected the output like this for every casher
ID : 12345
Name : test
Salary : $2000

Comment: What you really want is a function, not a loop or array. (You could also use a loop and an array, but it's overkill for just 2 cashiers.) Have you studied those yet?

Comment: @JimBalter no. i haven't study it yet

Comment: functions are the most powerful tool in programming ... I suggest waiting until you have learned about them, rather than using a loop here.

Comment: if you change `casher1,casher2` to `casher[2]`, then you have an array of two elements.

Comment: An array could be used, but then every reference needs to be indexed. I think it would be better to learn about functions and pointers first.

Comment: If you use a loop, you will also need an array. loops do not work very well with separate variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't learn functions yet, you should read a bit about them. I don't know what exactly you are trying to do, because you don't use the chasher's again, so as the code is now I don't know if you need to store them (but I will assume you do want to store them).

In that case, without the need of putting the cashers in an array you can create a function that accepts a casher as argument,

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct employee{
  char ID[6];
  char name[20];
  char address[50];
  long salary;
  long T;
}casher1,casher2;

int casherFunction(struct employee *casher);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int ch;
  printf("Choose : ");
  scanf("%d",&ch );
  if( 1 == ch ){
    casherFunction(&casher1);
  }else if( 2 == ch ){
    casherFunction(&casher2);
  }
  return 0;
}

int casherFunction(struct employee *casher){
   printf("Input Name : " );
    scanf("%s",casher->name );
    printf("Input ID : " );
    scanf("%s",casher->ID );
    printf("Input Salary : " );
    scanf("%ld",&casher->salary);
    printf("Input T : " );
    scanf("%ld",&casher->T );
    printf("\n");
    casher->salary = casher->salary + casher->T;

    printf("ID : %s\n",casher->ID );
    printf("Name : %s\n",casher->name );
    printf("Salary : %ld\n",casher->salary );
    return 0;
}
```

So here you first declare the function:

```
int casherFunction(struct employee *casher);
```

and then after the main you define it:

```
int casherFunction(struct employee *casher){
       printf("Input Name : " );
        scanf("%s",casher->name );
        printf("Input ID : " );
        scanf("%s",casher->ID );
        printf("Input Salary : " );
        scanf("%ld",&casher->salary);
        printf("Input T : " );
        scanf("%ld",&casher->T );
        printf("\n");
        casher->salary = casher->salary + casher->T;

        printf("ID : %s\n",casher->ID );
        printf("Name : %s\n",casher->name );
        printf("Salary : %ld\n",casher->salary );
        return 0;
    }
```

the return 0 is a standard return value when there are no errors.

Note also that the function expects a pointer `casherFunction(struct employee *casher)` that's why in the call to the function we write: `casherFunction(&casher1)` with the `&`.

Furthermore, elements in a struct pointer are under `casher->ID` instead of `casher.ID`.

Again, this is useful if you want the changes to be recorded in the cashers. then, you can for example, create a function to see a casher (is this case you won't need to pass a pointer, just a copy of the struct would be suffice).

The code would then be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct employee{
  char ID[6];
  char name[20];
  char address[50];
  long salary;
  long T;
}casher1,casher2;

int casherFunction(struct employee *casher);
int casherShow(struct employee casher);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int ch;
  printf("Choose : ");
  scanf("%d",&ch );
  if( 1 == ch ){
    casherFunction(&casher1);
  }else if( 2 == ch ){
    casherFunction(&casher2);
  }
    printf("%ld\n\n",casher1.salary);
    casherShow(casher1);

  return 0;
}

int casherFunction(struct employee *casher){
   printf("Input Name : " );
    scanf("%s",casher->name );
    printf("Input ID : " );
    scanf("%s",casher->ID );
    printf("Input Salary : " );
    scanf("%ld",&casher->salary);
    printf("Input T : " );
    scanf("%ld",&casher->T );
    printf("\n");
    casher->salary = casher->salary + casher->T;

    printf("ID : %s\n",casher->ID );
    printf("Name : %s\n",casher->name );
    printf("Salary : %ld\n",casher->salary );
    return 0;
}

int casherShow(struct employee casher){
    printf("Name: ");
    printf("%s\n",casher.name );
    printf("Input ID : " );
    printf("%s\n",casher.ID );
    printf("Salary : " );
    printf("%ld\n",casher.salary);
    return 0;   
}
```